# How can I make a second cout without destroying my first in this program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout, cin, carriage-return

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "thread"
#include "conio.h"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

void incrm();
void charget();

void main() {
    thread count(incrm);
    thread getcin(charget);

    count.join();
    getcin.join();

    cin.get();
}

void incrm() {
    int j = 0;    // used to increment and output
    while (true) {
        cout << "\r" << j;    // outputs 1,2,3,4... and so on
        j++;
        Sleep(150);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void charget() {
    while (true) {
        int i = getch();    // gets value of char
        cout << "\r\nCHAR: " << i;  // and here is the problem...!
    }
}
```

So I wanted this program to output a number in the first line, which increments without stopping and if you hit any key it should cout the value of that key in a secound line, so i wanted it to output something like this->

```
45
CHAR: 97
```

and after you have hit a key the incrementing number should stay in the first line. If you hit several keys the second cout should be overwritten, but this doesnt seem to work for me, my output looks like this if i hit several keys->

```
10
12AR: 97
20AR: 96
```

My problem is that my first cout (the incrementing number) overwrites my second (or my second my first I don't really know) and then this countinues for every line! :(

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 RC

Comment: you then may want to look at console handling, see for instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Standard C++ cannot do that. You need to talk to the operating system or terminal that you are using, either directly through the WinApi or with a library such as [ncurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm).

Comment: Ty CyberSpock it works now! :D

Comment: Sourcecode: http://oi58.tinypic.com/1y39er.jpg sorry for the picture, but cant comment that many characters

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use windows function called gotoxy(). You can apply this using

```
SetConsoleCursorPosition();
```

this function is availible in windows.h library.
It is possible to read more about it here:
[Link](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044844545&id=1043284392)